# I am facing hurdles for changing the layout of simple email form module how do customize layout of this?

Tags: css, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

```
 // uses $this->_labelAlign, $this->_col2space, $this->_errorTxtColor, $this->_field, $this->_maxFields
// if $this->_field[$x]['rows'] > 0 assumes text area
public function formatRow () 
{
    $output = '';
    for ($x = 1; $x <= $this->_maxFields; $x++) 
    {           
        if ($this->_field[$x]['active'] == 'Y' || $this->_field[$x]['active'] == 'R') {
            $name = 'mod_simpleemailform_field' . $x . '_' . $this->_instance;
            $value = (isset($_POST[$name])) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST[$name]) : '';
            // prevents Joomla from reformatting using javascript
            if (strpos($value, '@')) {
                $value = str_replace('@', '&#64;', $value);
            }
            // 2011-12-03 DB: added CSS classes for input, table, row, th and td
            $row = '';
            $row .= '<tr' . $this->_trClass   . '>';
            // labels
            $row .= "<th" . $this->_thClass    . " align='" . $this->_labelAlign . "'>" . $this->_field[$x]['label'] . "</th>";
            // space between cols
            $row .= "<td" . $this->_spaceClass . " width='" . $this->_col2space  . "'>&nbsp;</td>";
            // input field
            $row .= "<td" . $this->_tdClass    . ">";
            // check to see if text area
            if ($this->_field[$x]['rows'] > 0) {
                $row .= sprintf('<textarea name="%s" id="%s" rows="%d" cols="%d" %s>%s</textarea>',
                                $name,
                                $name,
                                $this->_field[$x]['rows'],
                                $this->_field[$x]['cols'],
                                $this->_inputClass,
                                $value);
            } else {
                $row .= sprintf('<input type="text" name="%s" id="%s" size="%d" value="%s" maxlength="%d" %s/>',
                                $name,
                                $name,
                                $this->_field[$x]['size'],
                                $value,
                                $this->_field[$x]['maxx'],
                                $this->_inputClass);
            }
            $row .= ($this->_field[$x]['error']) 
                  ? $this->formatErrorMessage($this->_errorTxtColor, $this->_field[$x]['error']) 
                  : '';
            $row .= "</td>";
            $row .= "</tr>\n";
            $output .= $row;
        }
    }
    return $output;
}
```

This is my module code for the output which shows in table format and i don't want this type of layout as a output... I had also try to do changes with tr, td and th tag but faild to get proper out... so please if anyone help me with this.

**Wrong format output what i am getting**

[image]

**Correct format output what i want**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here goes.  You have a series of

label
  spacer...
  input field

So replace the table with a

```
<div class='form-x'
```

and set its width as you need in the css, i.e.

```
div.form-x {width:450px; padding:12px;}
```

Then you want to replace the cells: the first th will become a label, the first td will be dropped altogther, the second will retain only its content (i.e. input or textarea).

To make your life easier, group each couple label-input within a div so:

```
<div class='formelement'>
  <label for='element-1'><?php echo $this->_labelAlign ?></label>
  <input ... or <textarea...
</div>
```

and in the css

```
div.formelement {padding:20px 0 0 0}
div.formelement label {display:block;}
div.formelement input, div.formelement textarea {width:100%}
```

Finally the submit button should be placed in a div with

```
div.submitbutton {text-align:center}
```

Regarding styling the input type=file, forget it. It's rendered differently by each browser, there are workarounds though but that's a different story.

Comment: I am still facing problem because they had not include any css..... above code (which i had put in my question) is written in helper.php file of module. so is there any solution for this?

Comment: of course just put the css in the template's custom css or add it with $document->addStyleDeclaration()